# Replace all commas BUT the main function ones?

Tags: javascript, php, regex

I am posting here because I've been searching for an answer for few hours already and lost many others more on trial and error on this website http://www.regexr.com/ for the best Regex possible.

I couldn't find anything to remove all commas but the first function ones.

#Quick Edit: I will always have the content of the function as a String on my php script, because I copy it from the file that originated the function call.

Here is an example:

```
MyClass::myFunction(
    array_merge($params, ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']),
    array_merge(["p01"], ["s01", "s02", "s03"]),
    oi("s04", "p02", "p03"),
    [["p05", "p06", "p07"],],
    [
        oi(),
        "p04",
        ["p05", "p06", "p07"],
        oi("p08", "p09", "p10", ["s05", "s06", "s07"]),
    ],
    [
        "p04",
        ["p05", "p06", "p07"],
        oi("p08", "p09", "p10", ["s05", "s06", "s07"]),
    ]
)
```

All I want is to replace all the commas but the myFunction ones ( The ones that separates it's params ).

I am already able to get all the content inside the myFunction brackets, so you don't have to deal with that.

---

#Edit: The reason I need this is because I developed a debug function for my project that shows exactly what variable/function/thing generated that code.

The oi() function is just a random function that is there for example purpose. On this case, it'll return an array with the parameters it received.

Here is how I do it:

Example:

```
$variable = 'This is a test variable. For the purpose os testing, 2 + 2 is ' . ( 2 + 2 );
MyClass::myFunction($variable);
```

1. After the function is executed, I get the function call params with debug_backtrace().
2. I copy the entire content of the called function from the file that executed it, so I get it as string.
3. I get only the content inside the function, removing the MyClass::myFunction( and the last ).
4. I explode the result by commas to get all the params of the function, but in that way, I explode the commas that I can't explode. I need a way to find which comma I need to explode.

Here is the final result of the example above ( As I can't post images, I'll type it ):

```
<pre>
    <pre class="source">variable</pre>
    <pre class="content"><small>string</small>'This is a test variable. For the purpose os testing, 2 + 2 is 4' <i>(length=63)</i></pre>
</pre>
```

Comment: Please reformulate your core question. *Why* do you want to remove the commas? From the shown source code? That would break the array declarations. What's the purpose? What is `oi()`?

Comment: PHP expression syntax is not a regular language (afaik), so you can't really do that with regex.

Comment: Why don't you use an existing tracer/debugger?

Comment: @DanFromGermany - Do you have any to suggest that does what I am trying to achieve here? I need to know what exactly generated that output. Be it a method call, array, object and so on.

Comment: Thanks for the people negativing the question and not saying why... Awesome support from this website. All I want is some tips... (y)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the help.

I came up with my own solution. I hope it is useful for anyone.

```
public static function extractParams($text)
{
    $firstOpen = '';
    $close = ['(' => ')', '[' => ']', '"' => '"', '\'' => '\''];
    $open = ['[', '(', '"', '\''];
    $counter = 0;
    $splittedString = str_split($text);
    $p = '';
    $param = [];
    foreach ($splittedString as $char) {
        $p .= $char;
        if (!$firstOpen) {
            if (in_array($char, $open)) {
                $firstOpen = $char;
                $counter = 1;
            }
        } else {
            if ($char === $firstOpen && !in_array($char, ['"', '\''])) {
                $counter += 1;
            } elseif ($char === $close[$firstOpen]) {
                $counter -= 1;
            }
            if ($counter === 0) {
                $param[] = trim(ltrim($p, ','));
                $p = '';
                $firstOpen = '';
            }
        }
    }
    if ($param === []) {
        $param[] = trim(ltrim($p, ','));
    }
    return $param;
}
```